# How to refresh UI of a picker control in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

I have 3 picker controls and I am trying to bind a single list to all the 3 picker controls. If one option is selected in first picker control then the same option should not repeat in rest of the 2 picker controls.I am not able to figure out how to implement it.

I tried using Security_Question_1_SelectedIndexChanged() in MainPage.cs file but the UI is not getting updated.

> MainPage.xaml:

```
 <Label x:Name="Security_Questions" Margin="0,20,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Security Questions" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="MediumVioletRed"></Label>
 <Picker x:Name="Security_Question_1" ItemsSource="{Binding SecurityQuestions_List}"  Title="Select question one" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="-4,0,0,0" FontSize="Micro">                                                                      
 </Picker>                                
 <Entry x:Name="Security_Answer_1" Placeholder="Type answer" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Micro"/>
 <Picker x:Name="Security_Question_2" ItemsSource="{Binding SecurityQuestions_List}" Title="Select question two" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="-4,0,0,0" FontSize="Micro">                                    
 </Picker>
 <Entry  x:Name="Security_Answer_2" Placeholder="Type answer" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="Micro"/>
 <Picker x:Name="Security_Question_3" ItemsSource="{Binding SecurityQuestions_List}" SelectedIndexChanged="Security_Question_3_SelectedIndexChanged" Title="Select question three" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="-4,0,0,0" FontSize="Micro">
```

> MainPage.cs file:

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new RegistrationPageViewModel();
    }

  private void Security_Question_1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var t1 = ((Xamarin.Forms.Picker)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (t1 == "What is your first vehicle number?")
            {                    
                this.Security_Question_2.ItemsSource.Remove("What is your first vehicle number?");
                this.Security_Question_3.ItemsSource.Remove("What is your first vehicle number?");
            }
            else if (t1 == "What is your child's nick name?")
            {
                this.Security_Question_2.ItemsSource.Remove("What is your child's nick name?");
                this.Security_Question_3.ItemsSource.Remove("What is your first vehicle number?");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Security_Question_2.ItemsSource.Remove("What is your first school name?");
                this.Security_Question_3.ItemsSource.Remove("What is your first vehicle number?");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

> RegistrationPageViewModel:

```
public RegistrationPageViewModel()
    {
        _department = new List<string>()

    {
        "What is your first vehicle number?",
        "What is your child's nick name?",
        "What is your first school name?"
    };
    }
    List<string> _department;

    public List<string> SecurityQuestions_List
    {
        get { return _department; }
        private set
        {
            _department = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to remove it from others pickers data, or do you want to avoid the user to select a duplicate value in each picker ?

Comment: I want to avoid the user to select duplicate value in each picker

Comment: If you use the same ItemSource.There will be some issue if you select the same picker more than once.So I suggest that you can use different ItemSourcewith the same content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use converter to 2 other Entries at ItemSource while you use Data Binding, passing the SelectedItem from the Entry as Converter Parameter and inside the converter you can remove the selected item that you passed as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to avoid the user to select duplicate value in each picker".

You can do something with property `SelectedItemProperty`, prob not the best way to do it, but one.

For each picker you bind property `SelectedItemProperty` to a property in the `ViewModel`. Setting null this property will do the job when a user select a value that is already set in the other picker. Let's say this with two pickers, you can easily adapt it to three pickers.

```
 <Picker x:Name="Security_Question_1" .... SelectedItemProperty="SelectedItemPicker1">                                    
 </Picker>
 <Picker x:Name="Security_Question_2" .... SelectedItemProperty="SelectedItemPicker2"> 
</Picker>
```

ViewModel

```
 public string SelectedItemPicker1
            {
                get => _selectedItemPicker1;
                set
                {
                    if (_selectedItemPicker1== value) return;
                    if (value == _selectedItemPicker2)
                    {
                        _selectedItemPicker2 = null;
                        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemPicker2");
                    }
                    _selectedItemPicker1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemPicker1");
                }
            }

            public string SelectedItemPicker2
            {
                get => _selectedItemPicker2;
                set
                {
                    if (_selectedItemPicker2 == value) return;
                    _selectedItemPicker2 = value == _selectedItemPicker1 ? null : value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemPicker2");
                }
            }
```

I'm not fan of having such logic in setters but as I said there should be a better approach.